# C++ - Generic struct's members give wrong values when assigning doubles (but works fine with integers)

Tags: c++, struct, double

I have a generic struct like the following (inside of a generic template):

```
struct AY_ALIGN(64) {
    T parm1;
    T parm2;
    T parm3;
    T parm4;
    T parm5;
};
```

When I assign the members with integers, the output is correct:

```
pr->u.p.parm1 = 0;
pr->u.p.parm2 = 2;
pr->u.p.parm3 = 1;
pr->u.p.parm4 = 1;
pr->u.p.parm5 = 1;

printf("The values: parm1=%i, parm2=%i, parm3=%i, parm4=%i, parm5=%i.\n",
        pr->u.p.parm1,
        pr->u.p.parm2,
        pr->u.p.parm3,
        pr->u.p.parm4,
        pr->u.p.parm5);
```

The printf() here gives the correct values.

**The problem happens, when using doubles like this:**

```
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm1 = 1.0;
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm2 = 2.0;
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm3 = 1.0;
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm4 = 1.0;
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm5 = 1.0;

printf("The values: parm1=%f, parm2=%f, parm3=%f, parm4=%f, parm5=%f.\n",
        *(double *)&pr->u.p.parm1,
        *(double *)&pr->u.p.parm2,
        *(double *)&pr->u.p.parm3,
        *(double *)&pr->u.p.parm4,
        *(double *)&pr->u.p.parm5);
```

The output here is:

```
parm1=0.000000
parm2=0.000000
parm3=0.000000
parm4=0.000000
parm5=1.000000
```

And when using other numbers like parm4=0.8754 (just an example), the output changes to very strange:

```
parm1=1.000000
parm2=0.000000
parm3=-85443653999189573105674489609599978349239364506618107894018364220379126235920356559839098648677109228247196955211621648453249973580988416.000000
parm4=0.000000
parm5=1.000000
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: you are missing to show us some code. Given only the fragments you posted we can only guess. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: When you start doing things like `*(double *)&` you should top and pause and ask yourself what you are really trying to accomplish.  Normally casting isn't doing to accomplish it.

Comment: why are you doing this casting at all? If your struct is parametrized on the type and `T` is either `int` or `double` you shouldnt need a single cast

Comment: Are the size of int and double the same? Sounds like UB

Comment: @JVApen: You would have UB even if size is same...

Comment: The thing is, I want to use this data structure for integers and doubles at the same time. :D

Comment: Then you should use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), because using `*(double *)&` is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem... Since the double takes more space than an integer, it occupies two of the members of the struct at the same time (this may depend). My possibilities are to either use the struct with an unassigned following member (gap) (which is a very bad idea although it would work ok my machine):

```
struct AY_ALIGN(64) {
    T parm1;
    T parm2;
    T parm3;
    T parm4;
    T parm5;
};
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm1 = 1.0;
//*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm2 = 2.0; // Do not assign parm2
*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm3 = 1.0;
//*(double *)&pr->u.p.parm4 = 1.0; // Do not assign parm4
pr->u.p.parm5 = 1; // Only space for an integer...
```

Or, to use, as you guys mentioned, a (second) struct with the correct type like this (which is the better solution):

```
struct AY_ALIGN(64) {
    double parm1;
    double parm2;
    double parm3;
    double parm4;
};
```

Comment: The size of an `int` and `double` is compiler and environment dependent, there is no guarantee about the correlation of the size between an `int` and a `double`. An `int` is defined to have at least `16` bytes but could also have `64` bytes. There are fixed with integer types that guarantee  certain size, but even then you are violating the goal type safety. Your first _"solution"_ is something you never ever want to have in you code, it won't pass any serious code review.

Comment: I agree that it depends. But I have to disappoint you... this code actually stems from the official LLVM OpenMP Runtime library. Go ahead and check yourself and you will find uses of exactly that casting. And you meant „bits“ not „bytes“. :)

Comment: Yes should be bits and not bytes, but the point is still true, that because of that reason the usage of that cast it problematic. Especially if you want to use it as sequential storage. And that it occurs in their source does not mean that it is good coding, and their comment `// may occupy parm3 and parm4` shows that they are aware of that. It is true that you can't avoid some of those constructs if you write a close to hardware layer, but it's definitely something that should not occur in regular c++ code.

Comment: So if you plan to use such a construct, and/or if you ask about something like this, then you need to always explain why you need to use that. Because otherwise it is just bad coding.

Comment: Oh wow you actually looked at the code? :D Yes I agree with everything you said! And you are also right that they only used it for the 3rd parameter (not continuously). But of course it’s still not nice. Thanks for the hints. I understand the reasons now why to avoid this.